# Can Isotope columnshift layout and centered items be combined?

Tags: jquery-isotope

I cannot get the elements centered when I try combining Isotope Centered layout and Column Shift layout.

Samples below:
**Centered layout** (working fine) - http://www.fiveblackcats.com/cl/stack/centered.html
**Column Shift layout** (working fine) - http://www.fiveblackcats.com/cl/stack/column_shift.html
**Combination of both** (column shift still working fine, but the elements are not centered) - http://www.fiveblackcats.com/cl/stack/column_shift.html

I'd appreciate if someone could point me out what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do this is to merge the 2 layouts properly.

I've done it but it's not clean at all. It need major refactor to avoid duplication of variables. But it works.

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.item',
    layoutMode: 'masonryColumnShift',
    masonry : {
      columnWidth : 292,
      gutterWidth: 10
    }
})
```

You can see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/Spope/AwMZ9/

I will try to clean this later if I can.